# Woocommerce subcategory 404

Tags: permalinks, woocommerce-offtopic

I need permalinks in my shop like

```
catalog/category/subcategory/productname
```

Now i have

**shop base**

```
catalog
```

**category base**

```
catalog
```

To make this i write to functions code

```
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', function( $rules )
{
    $new_rules = array(
        'catalog/([^/]*?)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
        'catalog/([^/]*?)/?$' => 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]',
    );
    return $new_rules + $rules;
} );
```

How it works?

so subcategory has url     `catalog/category/subcategory/` and give 404. When i delete /category from this url my subcategory works fine.

If i will return category base to default is it helps me? Or is it another way to do this?

I need permalinks in my shop like

```
catalog/category/subcategory/productname
```

or

```
product-cat/category/subcategory/productname
```

Need help please

Comment: Did you flush your rewrite rules? If not, just visit the admin page for permalinks, which automatically flushes them upon visiting.